# WPF: Click Detection on Path Nested inside Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, path

I have a bunch of paths programatically nested inside of a canvas.  I'm basically trying to figure out how click bubbling works.  How do I setup the canvas event handler to check if the point of the click was also on a path nested inside of the canvas.  This is my basic even code that works if the paths are not nested.

How do I add bubbling click detection?

```
void Path_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var item = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as Path;

   if (item != null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(item.Name);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you add a handler on the event UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent (as Path inherits it from there) on the Canvas

```
theNestingCanvas.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent , new RoutedEventHandler(target));

private void handler(object asd, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Path p = e.OriginalSource as Path;
    if (p != null)
    {
        //do whatever
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

like that you catch all bubbled UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUp events of elements within the canvas which are not handled somewhere else yet...

of course you can also add the handler on the Event `Path.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent` but after you will ask yourself why you catch also the MouseUp events of other nested elements...